# How is natality affected if sex isn't pleasurable anymore?

Tags: population, sex

Worldwide, every single person stopped enjoying sex. They still get attracted sexually but sex is basically frustrating and feels like it's always uncompleted.

Nobody has orgasm but still ejaculate so reproduction is still achievable.

In a world like this, how is natality affected?

---

Things to take in account:

- It's basically something just happened from one day to another
- Looks like something hormonal (Incapacity to segregate dopamine, serotonin, endorphin, etc... during sex)
- Everybody is affected the same way
- Only humans are affected

Comment: "*Nobody has orgasm but still ejaculate*" But men have to orgasm in order to ejaculate.

Comment: @RonJohn https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexual_anhedonia

Comment: Quoting the article, "cannot feel pleasure from **an orgasm**."  Thus, they still orgasm.

Comment: Ejaculatory anhedonia is the specifical term you are trying to ignore. I think it's still understandable.

Comment: Are you talking about males or both males and females?

Comment: @L.Dutch both. I think females are humans too.

Comment: Females can mate without reaching orgasm...

Comment: This question look like it is opinion based (which isn't allowed).  I don't think it is but I think that it would help if you reword the actual question a bit.  Maybe add what kinds of answers you are looking for or ask if there are any studies that show what might happen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Physical pleasure is the "reward" for taking action to procreate and spread copies of your genes.

Modern society has generally broken that link with contraceptives and the availability of abortions.  The birth rate in modern societies has dropped as a result.

However, some studies have shown that abortions don't significantly reduce the number of children a woman has in her lifetime but delays the birth of the first child until later in life when having children was a conscious decision.

So, you would likely see fewer pregnancies at lower ages but mostly the same total number of children in developed countries.

Also, you would likely see fewer cases STDs since there would be less incentive to engage in risky behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Western/First World birth rates (where there's already lots of birth control usage, and children aren't required to work the farm and take care of the elderly) would drop like a stone.  Certain segments of the population (mostly the rich and well-educated) would be virtually eliminated.

Agricultural societies where family-based farm labor is required would survive, but family sizes (and thus population growth) would be reduced, since the male wouldn't have the urges to take his wife whenever he felt like it.

Some segments of the population might survive, though, if the males use "number of children sired" as a way of showing that they do, in fact, enjoy sex.

Teen pregnancy would drop, too.

Comment: Rich and well-educated want their children too, even if they don't have farms to work on. Unlike in younger and less affluent families, their children often come as a result of careful planning, not momentary passion. Artificial insemination will become more popular, that's it, but families would still be targeting having 2-3 children, just like today.

Comment: @Alexander fertility rates are already below replacement level in the US and Europe... https://data.worldbank.org/indicator/SP.DYN.TFRT.IN

Comment: Yes, but it's a different issue, and it's pointing to the fact that sex has less and less to do with reproduction.

Comment: Religious organization in the past have always condemned sexual pleasure, especially in women, as in male is inevitable. This did not lower the fertility rates.

Comment: @L.Dutch because men took their pleasure.  There's no pleasure to take anymore.  MGTOW will get kicked up a notch or ten.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing would change, people have children because they want children not because sex is fun.

Having children by mistake is either the result of abuse or will result in the child being aborted if possible or otherwise just abandoned.

Comment: Intentional conceptions, yes.  Plenty of conceptions are oopses, though.